# S/MIME verification

Tags: encryption, openssl, smime

I am getting emails with smime.p7s attachments. when I look at my mail on my Linux box, I can see base64 encoded block in mail body. I can extract that block and open it on Windows using certmgr and everything looks ok.

I need to verify this certificate that I extracted to a file for

- CA path
- CRLs
- expiration

I want to perform all the task on linux using a script. How can I use openssl or some other command to do this?

Comment: You could probably use a java .jar file that uses Bouncy Castle... and invoke from the command line

Answer (score 2):

Openssl has all the command-line utilities you need.

It can work on [x509 certificates](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/x509.html#) and can also deal directly with [S/MIME content](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/smime.html). The [verify utility](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/verify.html) is specifically for doing certificate chain validation, but that function is also built in to the S/MIME utility.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes I am planning to use openssl to perform the tasks. However, currently, openssl don't like the format that I extract from mail command. That's where I need help :-(, e.g. my file starts with MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAQAAoIJNGTCCBcow
ggOyoAMCAQICBACYlowwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwWjELMAkGA1UEBhMCTkwxHjAcBgNVBAoMFVN0 Thanks S

Answer (score 2):

[You want to use](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41399/openssl-pkcs7-vs-s-mime) the `openssl cms` command:

```
openssl cms -verify -in somemail.eml
```

Note that the verification is done on the `.eml` file — not the `smime.p7s` attachment (the file beginning with “MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqC”).

For CRL checking, take a look at the `-crl_check` and `-crl_check_all` parameters.

To specify the CA certs to check against, use the `-CApath` or `-CAfile` parameters.

Finally, if you want to manually inspect the certificates yourself (like with *certmgr*) you could use the `-certsout` parameter:

```
openssl cms -verify -certsout chain.crt -in someemail.eml
openssl x509 -in chain.crt -text
```

If there is more than one cert in `chain.crt`, you can split them apart manually into separate files, so you can inspect each one individually with `openssl x509`.