# OpenSSL PKCS#7 vs. S/MIME

Tags: openssl, smime

OpenSSL 1.0.1c onwards seems to offer CMS support. I have difficulty understanding the difference between `smime` and `pkcs7`. S/MIME specs are layered on PKCS#7 (so says [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME)).

Now in `openssl` I have the following commands:

```
openssl smime 

openssl cms
```

Are these equivalent commands ? Why then have two implementations ?
When should either be used ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[PKCS#7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315) is an old standard from RSA Labs, published later on as an "informational RFC". Then, a new versions was produced, as an "Internet standard", i.e. with the seal of approval from the powers-that-be at IETF; a new name was invented for that: [CMS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2630). Newer versions were subsequently defined: [RFC 3369](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3369), [RFC 3852](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3852), [RFC 5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652). You can consider CMS and PKCS#7 to both designate the same standard, which has several versions.

CMS (PKCS#7) is a format for applying encryption, signatures and/or integrity checks on arbitrary binary messages (which can be large). It can be nested. It is the basis for some protocols such as [time stamping](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3161). It is also frequently (ab)used as a container for X.509 certificates: the `SignedData` type includes a field for a set of signatures (and that set can be empty), and *also* a field to store arbitrary X.509 certificates which are considered as "potentially useful" for whoever processes the object.

CMS is nominally backward compatible: there are version fields at various places, and a library which understands a version of CMS *should* be able to process messages from older versions; moreover, such a library should *also* produce messages which are compatible with other versions, inasmuch as it is feasible given the message contents. See [section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5.1) for an example: the "version" fields are set to the minimal values which still make sense given what else is in the structure.

---

[S/MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/MIME) is a protocol for doing "secure emails". S/MIME *uses* CMS for the cryptographic parts; what S/MIME adds over CMS is the following:

- Rules for encoding CMS objects (which are binary) into something which can travel unscathed in emails (which are text-based). These rules build on [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME), so basically Base64 with some headers.
- Canonicalization rules for signed but not encrypted emails, with "detached signatures". When an email is just signed, and the recipient might not be S/MIME-aware, it is convenient to send the signature as a CMS `SignedData` object which does *not* contain the email data itself; the signature is joined to the email as an attachment. It is then important to define exactly how the email contents are to be encoded into a sequence of bytes for the purpose of signature verification (a single mis-encoded bit would imply verification failure).
- Restrictions and usage practices on the actual CMS objects: how much nesting is allowed, what types may appear...
- Some extra attributes so that a sender may publish, in his signed messages, what kinds of cryptographic algorithms it supports and similar metadata.

In a way, we can think of S/MIME as the glue between CMS and emails.

---

[OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) is a library which implements some protocols, including some versions of PKCS#7 and CMS and S/MIME. The *library* also comes with *command-line tools* which expose, as a command-line interface, *some* functionalities of the library. The tools won't support anything that the library does not implement (the contrary would be surprising, to say the least), but the converse is not true: the library may implement features to which the command-line tools give no easy access, or no access at all.

Generally speaking, the command-line tools are not very "serious". They are convenient for some manual operations or a few scripts, but for robust *applications* you should use the library directly (it is a C library, but bindings exist for many programming languages).

Among the command line tools are the subcommands `pkcs7`, `cms` and `smime`. Confusingly, the `cms` command is meant to be used for S/MIME, and supports S/MIME, and turns out to be usable as a "generic" CMS support tool only as a byproduct. The OpenSSL developers created the new command `cms` in order to support recent versions of S/MIME (and CMS) because they felt that they could not update the `smime` command without breaking interface compatibility: third-party scripts using `openssl smime` would have become invalid, if the parameters for that command has been adjusted to account for newer S/MIME versions. So they just created a new command, called `cms`.

Theoretically, you should use `openssl cms` for everything related to S/MIME; but since that command gives access to the OpenSSL support code for the "new" versions of S/MIME and CMS, it necessarily allows you to produce S/MIME messages which are perfectly valid but use features that older implementations of S/MIME might not support. This is summarily described in [the man page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/cms.html#COMPATIBILITY_WITH_PKCS_7_format). Extensive tests with other S/MIME implementations (e.g. Thunderbird, Outlook...) are needed to know exactly what you can do with S/MIME without making your emails unreadable by other people.

Answer (score 6):

OpenSSL's `smime` app supports an older S/MIME format using PKCS#7 CMS, I'm guessing (partly based on the `standards.txt` distributed with OpenSSL) this is *S/MIME Version 3*.
The `cms` app in newer versions supports S/MIME v3.1 format messages, which use a newer CMS specification , so it's still S/MIME.
The `pkcs7` app handles *only* PKCS#7 v1.5 data, not any of the newer CMS versions.

I think nomenclature is less than clear, one might reasonably expect the `cms` app to behave like the the `pkcs#7` app.

The S/MIME Version 3.1 specification is in [RFC 3851](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3851).
The current version of S/MIME v3.2 is defined in [RFC 5751](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5751), where it describes it itself:

> S/MIME provides a consistent way to send and receive secure MIME data.

"PKCS#7 Cryptographic Message Syntax" is concerned with the the format of the cryptographic data (signatures, digests, encryption). "CMS" is the name for the current form of this. This [section of the CMS specification (RFC 5652)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-1.1.1) details changes over previous versions including [PKCS#7 v1.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2315).
CMS describes itself as

> The CMS describes an encapsulation syntax for data protection.  It
> supports digital signatures and encryption.  The syntax allows
> multiple encapsulations; one encapsulation envelope can be nested
> inside another.

One of the important changes in CMS relative to PKCS#7 v1.5 is that CMS is less tied to specific cryptographic algorithms or key management schemes (other than for interoperability requirements), so it is more extensible (see [RFC 3370](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3370) for example).

The standalone `cms` app appeared in openssl-1.0.0 (according to `CHANGES` anyway). As far as I understand it, various parts of the CMS data structures have their own independent version details, there isn't a simple "1.0" versioning system, the RFC number is probably the best way to identify an instance. Again, trusting `standards.txt`, OpenSSL's CMS support *seems* to be the [RFC336](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3369) instance.

If you need to create the most compatible S/MIME messages, the `smime` app is probably the best one to use. If you want to create or process newer versions, `cms` is better (there's probably also a better chance of successfully using newer/stronger encryption and digest algorithms with `cms`). The RFCs also allude to incompatibilities in S/MIME signatures across versions, and incompatibilities between CMS and PKCS#7.